# How to Hide navBar when open keyboard in a webView Android?

Tags: android

I created an app with a simple webView. When I click on an input and the keyboard appears I want to hide the bottom navigation bar. Someone Can help me?

I tried all properties of android:windowSoftInputMode="" but nothing

My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.michele.webapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_main.xml when I insert a simple webView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity
I setted all flag for full screen but when use keyboard the full screen don't work.

```
package it.michele.webapp;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "http://myphpsyte";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        hideSystemUI();
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testUrl();

    }

    public void testUrl(){
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        hideSystemUI();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        hideSystemUI();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

By using `animate` you can hide your **navBar**

To slide down i.e. to hide:

```
int height = bottomNavigationBar.getHeight
bottomNavigationBar.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
```

To slide up i.e. to set visible:

```
bottomNavigationBar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
```

Make sure you get reference to your `BottomNavigationBar`

```
BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar = findViewById(navBar_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q13vN.png)

I have not referred to BottomNavigationBar, but system navigation bar. In Android 8 and 9 immersive sticky work fine. In android 5, 6 and 7 when I click in a Edit in a webView and keyboard appears, navBar show. But I always want to hide navbar

The bar on the right